# how to show D-7 in data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a dimension column of "Date" and I want to create another "D-7" dimension where the date = date - 7. For example, when date = 2023-03-14, I want "D-7" to be 2023-03-07.

How should I do it? Thanks.

I tried `concat(year(date),month(date),date(date-7))`

but it shows error -

> invalid formula - Operator "-" doesn't support DATE - NUMBER. Operator "-" supports NUMBER - NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

> invalid formula - Operator "-" doesn't support DATE - NUMBER.

`Date` column appears a `DATE` type. If so, try [DATETIME_SUB](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9699809?hl=en&ref_topic=7583292) instead.

```
DATETIME_SUB(Date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```